# OLAP function on temporary table?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying a query like

```
    select (*) 
    from (select row_number() over (order by a.id desc)SNo, 
                 a.id,
                 b.EmpName 
          from mySchema.table1 a
          INNER JOIN mySchema.table2 b on a.EmpCode=b.EmpCode 
          where UPPER(b.EmpName) LIKE 'AB%') z
```

This does not work as long as I use 'UPPER' in the temporary table. I have to use UPPER OLAP function because the Emp names in my table are not alike (Some being 'ALice' , some 'boB').

**Edit**

> **It returns SQL0255] Reason code:6 OLAP function not supported.**

The problem is that I cannot use UPPER and row_number() together. My platform is DB2 ISeries V5R4.
Is there someway I can execute the UPPER function ?

Comment: In what way does this query "not work" if you use UPPER? Does it return an error? If so, which one? Does it return data, but incorrectly processed? If so, how? Where is the temporary table in this scenario?

Comment: Please check my updated reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer would be to do the UPPER selection in the sub-query, and derive the row number in the main query - like so:

```
select row_number() over (order by id desc)SNo, 
       z.*
from (select a.id,
             b.EmpName 
      from mySchema.table1 a
      INNER JOIN mySchema.table2 b on a.EmpCode=b.EmpCode 
      where UPPER(b.EmpName) LIKE 'AB%') z
```

- assuming DB2 will permit it.